# How to generate thumbnails of PDFs for files uploaded to civicrm file fields

Tags: files

Title says it. There are a number of Drupal modules which take care of this if the field is on a drupal entity but we are using civicrm fields (via a webform but pretty sure that is beside the point)

https://www.drupal.org/project/pdfthumb
https://www.drupal.org/project/pdfpreview

The actual Goal - in case someone has another route entirely is:
- folk submit a webform including uploading various files eg Passports
- markers are then given a webform that loads the Activity via aid in the url
- above the webform we pull in a Drupal View Block that loads the files related to the Activity (again by checking the aid in the url)

So it is via that View that we are hoping to show a thumbnails of the PDF rather than showing just a link to the file.